# Getting Jenkins to run like the Selenium IDE

Tags: testing, selenium, jenkins

I've been using Selenium IDE for regression tests, but as the number of test cases increases, I've moved it over to Jenkins to run.

However, some tests that run perfectly in Selenium IDE fail in Jenkins. Simple commands like verifying text presence.

Is it just me? Has someone else encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding the command `waitForElementPresent` and maybe a small pause (like 1000 ms) before you verify the text is present.

We ran into similar issues; the tests would run fine locally, but break on Jenkins.  Slowing it down seemed to do the trick for us.  Add more details to what your failing tests look like if this doesn't help.